# Problem with former RAID hard drive settings in Linux Mint 17

Tags: linux, linux-mint, hard-disk, hardware, raid

I'm new to Linux, just installed Linux Mint for the first time. I have two hard drives which were previously in a RAID configuration. Now before I have installed Linux I've changed them to individual drives.

- I've changed BIOS setting to AHCI
- I've switched off the J Micron RAID controller
- I've changed drive signatures under Windows 7

They are properly detected and working in Windows 7, but in Linux even though they're visible in “Devices” as two individual drives the system is unable to mount them. GParted still displays:

```
/dev/mapper/isw_ccjafbfdhc_RAID_Volume0 with all space unallocated.
```

When I display information for an individual disk it says:

```
The device /dev/sdc1 doesn't exist
Unable to read the contents of this file system!
Because of this some operations may be unavailable.
The cause might be a missing software package.
The following list of software packages is required for ntfs file system 
    support:  ntfsprogs / ntfs-3g.
```

What should I do in order to access these drives in Linux? Please point me in the right direction.

#### UPDATE

After booting to Windows again, the two HDDs had again the same signature, and unfortunately the same file structure i.e. files were overwritten with files from the second hard drive. Fortunately I had them backed up.

Comment: It looks like the disks are formatted with NTFS. What does the output of `sudo sfdisk -l` and provide the output in your Q so we can assist further.

Comment: @slm will do it soon as I recover all the files and then be able to switch to linux.

Answer (score 1):

Have solved the problem. By examining the disks I've found out that disks had individual windows disk signatures which allowed them to work properly in windows environment. However Linux had still seen them as RAID configuration.

What I had to do is to switch back on the RAID controller  and remove the drives from RAID configuration at BIOS level.  Before I did that I was trying to  change the signature using wxHexEditor which resulted that the RAID controller was detecting them as not RAID members, however the MBR became corrupted.